# Problemas con un Formulario de actualizacion php , Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un formulario para actualizar datos en una base de datos lo que me hace este formulario es que no me actualiza nada pero tampoco tira ERROR

---

```
$host="localhost";
$usuario="root";
$contraseña="";
$base="comercio";

$conexion= new mysqli($host, $usuario, $contraseña, $base);
if ($conexion -> connect_errno)
{
    die("Fallo la conexion:(".$conexion -> mysqli_connect_errno().")".$conexion-> mysqli_connect_error());
}

/////////////////////// CONSULTA A LA BASE DE DATOS ////////////////////////

$alumnos="SELECT * FROM kiosco";
$resAlumnos=$conexion->query($alumnos);
?>

<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Actualizar Registros PHP</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>

    <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="alert alert-info">
        <h2>Actualizar Registros de la BD con PHP</h2>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section>
        <form method="post">
        <table class="table">

            <tr>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>tipo</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
            </tr>

            <?php

            while ($registroKiosco = $resKiosco->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))

            {

                echo'<tr>

                    <td hidden ><input name="Cod[]" value="'.$registroKiosco['Codigo'].'" /></td>

                     <td><input name= "Cod['.$registroKiosco['Codigo'].']" value="'.$registroKiosco['Codigo'].'" /></td>
                     <td><input name= "Prod['.$registroKiosco['Codigo'].']" value="'.$registroKiosco['Productos'].'" /></td>
                     <td><input name= "tip['.$registroKiosco['Codigo'].']" value="'.$registroKiosco['tipo'].'" /></td>
                     <td><input name= "Prec['.$registroKiosco['Codigo'].']" value="'.$registroKiosco['Precio'].'"/></td>
                     </tr>';
            }


            ?>

        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="actualizar" value="Actualizar" class="btn btn-info col-md-offset-9" />
    </form>

    <?php

        if(isset($_POST['actualizar']))
        {
            foreach ($_POST['Cod'] as $Cods) 
            {
                $editCod=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['Cod'][$Cods]);
                $editProd=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['Prod'][$Cods]);
                $edittip=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['tip'][$Cods]);
                $editPrec=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['Prec'][$Cods]);

                $actualizar=$conexion->query("UPDATE kiosco SET Codigo='$editCod', Productos='$editProd', tipo='$edittip', Precio='$editPrec' WHERE Codigo='$Cods'");
            }

            if($actualizar==true)
            {
                echo "DATOS ACTUALIZADOS CORRECTAMENTE! <a href='actualizarr.php'>CLICK AQUÍ</a>";
            }

            else
            {
                echo "ERROR NO SE PUDO ACTUALIZAR DATOS!";
            }
        }

    ?>



    </section>

    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: En primera te recomiendo que tus consultas las definas como recomienda PHP http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php por medio de consultas preparadas, en segundo intenta ver que trae tu variable $Cods porque es la que condiciona en tu where, a lo mejor trae un valor que no tiene registros y por eso no te manda error ya que la consulta puede ser verdadera sin afectar ninguna fila, ademas únicamente estas verificando la ultima inserción porque tu If esta fuera de tu foreach

Comment: Además de tener en cuenta los comentarios bde MGress, cuando haces el update no deberías hacer un set del campo que utilizas como condición, que es Codigo. Puedes hacer un echo de la query para comprobar que rellenar adecuadamente todos los campos.

Comment: Tu código es vulnerable a la Inyección SQL. Actualmente se recomienda usar consultas preparadas. En este caso, no sólo darán seguridad a tus datos, sino que te permitirán optimizar el script, ya que sólo tienes que preparar la consulta una sola vez y luego pasar un arreglo con los parámetros del UPDATE que podrás crear con la ayuda de `call_user_func_array`. Al final, ejecutas la consulta al salir del bucle ... no cada cada vez dentro del mismo, lo cual tendrá su costo, sobre todo si es un bucle muy grande. Y si usas PDO, crear un UPDATE dinámico y ejecutarlo es mucho más fácil.

Comment: Me parece que voy a tener que seguir estudiando un poco mas. voy a seguir sus consejos y en unos días les digo como me fue !!Gracias

Comment: El problema era en la base de datos la primera fila estaba vacía tenia algunas variables mal declaradas cosas que uno por falta de experiencia y conocimiento pasa por alto, ahora funciona y voy a ver lo de la seguridad.   !!Muchísimas gracias